# Eclipse not opening as JRE is not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using eclipse Keepler till yesterday it was opening and I was able to use it but today it is not opening and getting this error.

[image]

googled but found asnwers that can be applied only after eclipse is opened but my problem is eclipse is not opening.

Please advice me what to be done between I am using eclipse keepler to develop android applications.

Thanks in advance
Siva

Comment: have you changed anything? What is the value of `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: Thans @RossDrew for the hint

Comment: It often happens if you move the Java folder...

Answer (score 2):

In the directory of your eclipse there is a file called 'eclipse.ini'. open it with a notepad and add the vm-path. for example:

```
-vm
c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/javaw.exe
```

Maybe it works

Comment: There is no path like you mentioned in config file.

Comment: got it... path was not set in environmnent variables but still confused why it was working before... anyway thanks

Answer (score 2):

check your java path in eclipse.ini (configuration settings) file which is located at your eclipse path

the first line should be:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/bin/javaw.exe
```

Comment: I posted this before seeing your answer.

Comment: There is no path like you mentioned in config file.

Comment: got it... path was not set in environmnent variables but still confused why it was working before... anyway thanks